# Problems registering and logging in a user using Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wanting to enable the use of a third-party account (in my case a Google account) to create a new user without having to fill out the normal user registration form, but I'm having problems logging in with the user that I registered using the account third

On my login.blade.php page the error **Route [google.login] not defined.** is being pointed at the button

**login.blade.php**

```
   <div class="ml-3">
    <a href="{{ route('google.login') }}" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent
        rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none
        focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150'"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>Google Login</a>
   </div>
```

**register.blade.php**

```
   <div class="ml-3">
   <a href="{{ route('google.register') }}" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent
   rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none
   focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150'">
   <i class="fa fa-google"></i>Google signup</a>
   </div>
```

**services.php**

```
    'google' => [ // Google account
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL'),
    ],
```

**.env**

```
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXX"
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXX"
    GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google/callback"
```

**web.php**

```
    Route::controller(GoogleSocialiteController::class)->group(function() {
       // Login
       Route::get('auth/google/redirect', 'redirectGoogleLogin')->name('google.login');
       Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'callbackGoogleLogin');
       // Register
       Route::get('auth/google/redirect', 'redirectGoogleRegister')->name('google.register');
       Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'callbackGoogleRegister');
    });
```

**GoogleSocialiteController.php**

```
class GoogleSocialiteController extends Controller
    {
    
    public function redirectGoogleLogin()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function callbackGoogleLogin(Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

            $user = User::firstOrCreate([
                'email' => $user->email
            ], [
                'name' => $user->name,
                'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(24))
            ]);

            Auth::login($user, true);

            return redirect('dashboard');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('login')->with('success-destroy', "Unable to authenticate a Google account that is not linked to your registration.");
        }
    }

    public function redirectGoogleRegister()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function callbackGoogleRegister()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        $exists_user = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();

        if ($existe_user) {
            return redirect('login')->with('success-destroy',"$user->name already linked this Google account when registering in the system.");
        } else {
            $new_user = new User();
            $new_user->name = $user->name;
            $new_user->email = $user->email;
            $new_user->password = Hash::make(Str::random(24));
            $new_user->save();

            Auth::login($new_user, true);
        }
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

How i fix this problem?

Comment: In your `web.php` file, you have defined two routes with the same URI

Comment: I know, but i have difficult in solve this.